# how to solve using regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am getting android url from json like this

```
"https:\/\/play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details?id=com.lego.starwars.thenewyodachronicles&amp;hl=en"
```

now I want only Package name from above URL :-> "com.lego.starwars.thenewyodachronicles"

How would i solve it using Regular expression in javascipt

Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a lookahead.

```
[^=&]+(?=&)
```

Code:

```
> "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lego.starwars.thenewyodachronicles&amp;hl=en".match(/[^=&]+(?=&)/g)
[ 'com.lego.starwars.thenewyodachronicles' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*?=([\w.]+).*$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kM7rT8/9